# Tableau - Bins based on Fixed LOD Customer Units

Tags: tableau-api

**What I'm trying to do:**  Create a histogram showing the distribution of customers based on their annual ordering size (1-10 units, 11-50, and so on) based on a Combined Field (Child + Zip Code which is our definition of a customer).

**Problem:**  I cannot figure out a way to calculate the different bins correctly.  I've seen plenty of posts for using bins in Tableau but none calculated based off a unique id like mine.  It seems the customers are being put in every category (1-10, 11-20, etc...) instead of a unique category if their unit sales go beyond the <= .  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding FIXED LOD calcs.

**End goal:** Get a count of the customers in these different ordering ranges to display on a histogram.

**Having no luck with this formula:**

```
IF { FIXED [UID_Cust] : SUM([Units]) } <= 10 THEN '1-10'
ELSEIF { FIXED [UID_Cust] : SUM([Units]) } <= 20 THEN '11-20'
ELSEIF { FIXED [UID_Cust] : SUM([Units]) } <= 50 THEN '21-50'
ELSEIF { FIXED [UID_Cust] : SUM([Units]) } <= 250 THEN '51-250'
ELSE '>250'
END
```

Here is a picture of what I'm currently getting.  Everything would be perfect if I could replace those little blocks with just one number, the count of the customers in that range.
[image: Current Result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was the LOD calc.  I needed to add the year since I forgot Fixed LOD ignores worksheet filters.

```
{ FIXED [UID_Cust], [Order_Date] = 2017 : SUM([Units]) }
```

Then I saved this as an individual table calc "UID_Sales"

```
IF [UID_Sales] <= 10 THEN '1-10'
ELSEIF [UID_Sales] <= 20 THEN '11-20'
ELSEIF [UID_Sales] <= 50 THEN '21-50'
ELSEIF [UID_Sales] <= 250 THEN '51-250'
ELSE '>250'
END
```